# Solving ambiguities in grammars

Tags: parsing, grammar, bison, lexer, flex-lexer

I am writing a parser for delphi's dfm's files. The lexer looks like this:

```
EXP ([Ee][-+]?[0-9]+)

%%

("#"([0-9]{1,5}|"$"[0-9a-fA-F]{1,6})|"'"([^']|'')*"'")+ { 
                                                 return tkStringLiteral; }
"object" { return tkObjectBegin; }
"end" { return tkObjectEnd; }
"true" { /*yyval.boolean = true;*/ return tkBoolean; }
"false" { /*yyval.boolean = false;*/ return tkBoolean; }

"+" | "." | "(" | ")" | "[" | "]" | "{" | "}" | "<" | ">" | "=" | "," | 
":" { return yytext[0]; }

[+-]?[0-9]{1,10} { /*yyval.integer = atoi(yytext);*/ return tkInteger; }
[0-9A-F]+ { return tkHexValue; }
[+-]?[0-9]+"."[0-9]+{EXP}? { /*yyval.real = atof(yytext);*/ return tkReal; }
[a-zA-Z_][0-9A-Z_]* { return tkIdentifier; }
"$"[0-9A-F]+ { /* yyval.integer = atoi(yytext);*/ return tkHexNumber; }

[ \t\r\n] { /* ignore whitespace */ }
. { std::cerr << boost::format("Mystery character %c\n") % *yytext; }

<<EOF>> { yyterminate(); }

%%
```

and the bison grammar looks like

```
%token tkInteger
%token tkReal
%token tkIdentifier
%token tkHexValue
%token tkHexNumber
%token tkObjectBegin
%token tkObjectEnd
%token tkBoolean
%token tkStringLiteral

%%object:
    tkObjectBegin tkIdentifier ':' tkIdentifier 
          property_assignment_list tkObjectEnd
  ;

property_assignment_list:
    property_assignment
  | property_assignment_list property_assignment
  ;

property_assignment:
    property '=' value
  | object
  ;

property:
    tkIdentifier
  | property '.' tkIdentifier
  ;

value:
    atomic_value
  | set
  | binary_data
  | strings
  | collection
  ;

atomic_value:
    tkInteger
  | tkReal
  | tkIdentifier
  | tkBoolean
  | tkHexNumber
  | long_string
  ;

long_string:
    tkStringLiteral
  | long_string '+' tkStringLiteral
  ;

atomic_value_list:
    atomic_value
  | atomic_value_list ',' atomic_value
  ;

set:
    '[' ']'
  | '[' atomic_value_list ']'
  ;

binary_data:
    '{' '}'
  | '{' hexa_lines '}'
  ;

hexa_lines:
    tkHexValue
  | hexa_lines tkHexValue
  ;

strings:
    '(' ')'
  | '(' string_list ')'
  ;

string_list:
    tkStringLiteral
  | string_list tkStringLiteral
  ;

collection:
    '<' '>'
  | '<' collection_item_list '>'
  ;

collection_item_list:
    collection_item
  | collection_item_list collection_item
  ;

collection_item:
    tkIdentifier property_assignment_list tkObjectEnd
  ;

%%

void yyerror(const char *s, ...) {...}
```

The problem with this grammar occurs while parsing the binary data. Binary data in the dfm's files is nothing
but a sequence of hexadecimal characters which never spans more than 80 characters per line. An example of
it is:

```
Picture.Data = {
      055449636F6E0000010001002020000001000800A80800001600000028000000
      2000000040000000010008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

      ...

      FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000FF000000FF000000FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000}
```

As you can see, this element lacks any markers, so the strings clashes with other elements. In the example
above the first line is returns the proper token `tkHexValue`. The second however returns a `tkInteger` token
and the third a `tkIdentifier` token. So when the parsing comes, it fails with an *syntax error* because
binary data is composed only of `tkHexValue` tokens.

My first workaround was to require integers to have a maximum length (which helped in all but the last line
of the binary data). And the second was to move the `tkHexValue` token above the `tkIdentifier` but it means
that now I will not have identifiers like `F0`

I was wondering if there is any way to fix this grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved this one. I needed to define a state so `tkHexValue` is only returned while reading binary data. In the preamble part of the lexer I added

```
%x BINARY
```

and modify the following rules

```
"{" {BEGIN BINARY; return yytext[0];}
<BINARY>"}" {BEGIN INITIAL; return yytext[0];}
<BINARY>[ \t\r\n] { /* ignore whitespace */ }
```

And that was all!